# can't catch an exception from a function in c++

Tags: c++, exception

Like the title said, I can't catch an exception thrown by a function. It just says "terminate called after throwin an instance of tocccli::InvalidParametersError*"

```
try{
  cmd_parameters = parse_cmd(argc, argv);
}
catch (InvalidParametersError e){
  // blablabla
}
```

The function that throws the exception

```
std::vector<CmdParam> parse_cmd(int argc, char* argv[]){
for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
{
  if (argv[i][0] == '-')
  {
   //blablala
  }
  else
  {
    if (result.empty())
    {
      throw new InvalidParametersError(
          "First parameter have to be an option (e.g. starts with a dash)");
    }

    result.back().arguments.push_back(argv[i]);
  }
}

return result;
}
```

the function is inside a namespace called tocccli
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't throw with the `new` keyword in `parse_cmd()`:

```
std::vector<CmdParam> parse_cmd(int argc, char* argv[]){
for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
{
  if (argv[i][0] == '-')
  {
   //blablala
  }
  else
  {
    if (result.empty())
    {
      throw InvalidParametersError(  // <-- No new keyword here
          "First parameter have to be an option (e.g. starts with a dash)");
    }

    result.back().arguments.push_back(argv[i]);
  }
}

return result;
}
```

Catch by const reference:

```
try{
  cmd_parameters = parse_cmd(argc, argv);
}
catch (const InvalidParametersError& e){
  // blablabla
}
```

Comment: it worked! but... why? what's the difference between new X() and X()?

Comment: Think of a function named catch (it's not, but just bear with me).  When X is created with X(), it can be passed to catch(X), catch(X&), or catch(const X&).  When X is created with new X(), you need catch to handle the pointer to X, like catch(X*) or catch(const X*).
Of course, creating an exception dynamically with new also introduces the problem of how to free the memory.  You'd have to delete the X* in the exception handler, which is decidedly non-canonical.  Normally exceptions are created off the stack and caught by reference.

Answer (score 3):

You are throwing a pointer to an InvalidParametersError, and catching by value. Consider changing your throw to:

`throw InvalidParametersError("First parameter have to be an option (e.g. starts with a dash)");`

And as pointed out by @pmr, also consider catching by const ref

```
try {
    cmd_parameters = parse_cmd(argc, argv);
} catch (const InvalidParametersError &e) {
    // ....
}
```

Comment: And also consider to catch by reference in case you want polymorphic exceptions.

Answer (score -2):

just add ampersand in front of the error you want to catch, in the catch block and done.

```
catch (InvalidParametersError &e)
```